# Docker (alpine) file not found when CMD

Tags: docker, busybox, alpine

So this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add --update --upgrade --no-cache mysql mysql-client

RUN rm -rf /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/* /etc/mysql.d/ && \
mkdir -p /var/lib/mysql /var/run/mysqld && \
chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql /run/mysqld && \
chgrp -R mysql /var/lib/mysql /run/mysqld && \
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --ldata=/var

EXPOSE 3306

USER mysql

CMD ["sh", "mysqld_safe --data=/var"]
```

My issue is that when I run the container with the image it does not find `mysqld_safe`.
But when I run the command manually like this: `docker run mysql mysqld_safe --data=/var` it works !
I try to change the dockerfile with:
`CMD ["sh", "cat -"]`
to see if the problem is with the `mysqld_safe` command but same issue here, it does not find `cat` except when I run it with `docker run mysql cat -`.

Is the problem come from `busybox` on alpine, or from PATH ? I have no idea for now and I require you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `-c` flag to `sh` that tells it to parse/run the next argument to the shell. Without that, I believe it's looking for a script with the name `mysqld_safe --data=/var` to run, that's not the script `mysqld_safe` with the arg `--data=/var`, but a single script name with a space, dashes, and equals sign in the directory name. Instead you want:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "mysqld_safe --data=/var"]
```

Comment: Oh it actually works thanks ! :)